# what to do when you forget something that you intended to say?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

I was thinking to myself, how an English native speaker might act when goes blank about something that was about to say?

Take this conversation as an example:

> Eric: Did you notice what happened when you came to the class?
>
> Tim: Nah, I have no idea.
>
> Eric: uh...er... it just slipped my mind... er ...[here's the action, when he's trying to remember but nothing comes up]

Obviously it's a hypothetical situation, but I want to know what kind of actions might be taken by Eric and what additional things he might say when he keeps trying to remember but he still doesn't?

Comment: *I can't remember or I forgot  what I was going to say.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These expressions are used regularly:

> [My mind's gone blank](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/your-mind-is-a-blank-goes-blank)
>
> Just a minute, it's [on the tip of my tongue](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-tip-of-your-tongue)

Comment: Or maybe [it's slipped my mind](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/something-slipped-my-mind).

Comment: "on the tip of my tongue" is commonly understood to mean you had not been able to recall something in the first place, but feel that recall should be possible and may happen soon.  "My mind's gone blank" means you knew it then suddenly forgot, whether or not you'll be able to recall it.  Personally I would go with a variation of the comment above: "Hold on, I forgot what I was going to say...uhh" then stall in the hopes that I'll remember before the other person speaks again.